# Angular-Ionic HttpClient Post request to Asp.net Api retruns 400 but swagger returns 200/401

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, http-headers

I have a Ionic App and a asp.net Api.

To authorize I send the Login Credentials in a Post request.

Swagger returns this:
[image: correct login 200 response]

or
[image: wrong login 401 response]

When sending my Post request like this:

```js
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'content-Type': 'application/json', 'accept': '*/*' })
  };

  login(credentials: {username: string; pw: string}): Observable <any>
  {
    return this.http.post('https://localhost:7206/auth/login', credentials, this.httpOptions)
  }
```

I get a 400 Error

[image: Chrome Network Post]

I don't know much about Http requests and all the answers I could find for http 400 errors is change the content type to aplication/json, which I already did.

Any Help/Tipps/Ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your API is, in the request body, expecting properties with the names `name` and `password`. But in your angular code it seems like you are sending the request body which only contains properties `username` and `pw`.

This is probably the reason why your server is sending a 400 error, which means you were sending a bad request (e.g. when your request body is not matching the expected schema).